# Work with JSON file on Python

Tags: python, json, google-chrome, bookmarks

I have a Google Chrome Bookmark file, and it's in JSON format

```
{
   "checksum": "b884cbfb1a6697fa9b9eea9cb2054183",
   "roots": {
      "bookmark_bar": {
         "children": [ {
            "date_added": "12989159740428363",
            "id": "4",
            "name": "test2",
            "type": "url",
            "url": "chrome://bookmarks/#1"
         } ],
         "date_added": "12989159700896551",
         "date_modified": "12989159740428363",
         "id": "1",
         "name": "bookmark_bar",
         "type": "folder"
      },
      "other": {
         "children": [ {
            "date_added": "12989159740428363",
            "id": "4",
            "name": "test",
            "type": "url",
            "url": "chrome://bookmarks/#1"
         } ],
         "date_added": "12989159700896557",
         "date_modified": "0",
         "id": "2",
         "name": "aaa",
         "type": "folder"
      },
      "synced": {
         "children": [  ],
         "date_added": "12989159700896558",
         "date_modified": "0",
         "id": "3",
         "name": "bbb",
         "type": "folder"
      }
   },
   "version": 1
}
```

and in Python format:

```
{'checksum': 'b884cbfb1a6697fa9b9eea9cb2054183', 'version': 1, 'roots': {'synced': {'name': 'bbb', 'date_modified': '0', 'children': [], 'date_added': '12989159700896558', 'type': 'folder', 'id': '3'}, 'bookmark_bar': {'name': 'bookmark_bar', 'date_modified': '12989159740428363', 'children': [{'url': 'chrome://bookmarks/#1', 'date_added': '12989159740428363', 'type': 'url', 'id': '4', 'name': 'test2'}], 'date_added': '12989159700896551', 'type': 'folder', 'id': '1'}, 'other': {'name': 'aaa', 'date_modified': '0', 'children': [{'url': 'chrome://bookmarks/#1', 'date_added': '12989159740428363', 'type': 'url', 'id': '4', 'name': 'test'}], 'date_added': '12989159700896557', 'type': 'folder', 'id': '2'}}}
```

I'm writing a bookmark manager now.
I want to move the web pages by name. 
For example: mv /bookmark_bar/test2 /other/test2

But every web pages are dictionaries, and they are in a list. So, I must use index to locate the web pages, **I can't locate them by name**.

Any ideas?

Comment: You do have bookmarks don't you? (Just try adding stackoverflow.com (for example) and see if that appears...)

Comment: I want to write a bookmark manager in Python.

Comment: Just out of curiosity - is there a difference that I don't see in the first JSON and it's corresponding python format?

Comment: Yes, there's no difference.
Just different quotes used but this doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it what you need https://gist.github.com/3332055 ?

Comment: Yes, that is! But I need to convert back too. And I have my own solution now.

Answer (score 0):

An example of how to iterate over the structure - exactly what you want to do with it then, is up to you:

```
for root, val in bm['roots'].iteritems():
    print root, 'is named', val['name']
    for child in val['children']:
        print '\t', child['name'], 'is at', child['url']
```

Comment: It doesn't help me, because I wrote one already.

The Main Ploblem is: Every web pages are dictionaries, and they are in a list. So, I must use index to locate the web pages(a['roots']['bookmark_bar'][0], not a['roots']['bookmark_bar']['pages']), I can't locate them by name.

Comment: @比尔盖子 You should be putting this information into your question, rather than 1) attempting to edit my answer and 2) so that people can more easily see what you have tried, what isn't working, and assist you better

Answer (score 0):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import json
def hook(pairs):
    o = {}
    for k, v in pairs.iteritems():
        o[str(k)] = v
    return o

jsonString = """{"a":"a","b":"b","c":{"c1":"c1","c2":"c2"}}"""
r = json.loads(jsonString, object_hook=hook)


assert r['c']['c1'] == "c1"
del r['c']['c1']
assert not r['c'].has_key('c1')
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what are you doing.